# Change format of tabs title in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way of customizing title of Tabs?
Something similar to Title Bar customization with {currentFile}, {separator} etc.

My main goal is to show group number in tab bar somewhere. I would like to do something like:

`{groupNumber} {separator} {currentFile} {separator} {currentFilePath}`

To have:

`1 | test | c:\users\current\test`

May be you have any recommendations. Thanks.